# ios drag and drop subview only working once

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, drag-and-drop

I have  UIView in which I want to be able to drag and drop subviews, and this is working fine *once*.

```
- (void)pan: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        CGPoint startPos = [recognizer locationInView:self];
        for (UIControl *sv in self.subviews){
            if ([sv pointInside:startPos withEvent:nil]){
                 self.controlBeingDragged = sv;
            }
         }
     }
     if (((recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
         (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) &&
         self.controlBeingDragged){
         CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
         self.controlBeingDragged.center = CGPointMake(self.controlBeingDragged.center.x + translation.x, self.controlBeingDragged.center.y + translation.y);
         [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
         if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
             self.controlBeingDragged = nil;
         }

     }
 }
```

However, if I try to drag the same UIControl again, the containing view no longer knows where it is. I can drag it again by starting at the original position, so clearly there is something I am not doing to inform the containing view that its subview has moved. But what?

Comment: When you try dragging the same control again, which part of the above code is not getting run; if you use trace-writes, or the debugger, what lines aren't being reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised it's even working once.  The `pointInside:withEvent:` message requires a point in the *receiver's* coordinate system, but you're sending a point that's in the receiver's *superview's* coordinate system. You can use `convertPoint:toView:` for each subview to convert the point to the subview's coordinate system before sending the point in the `pointInside:withEvent:` message.

```
CGPoint subviewPoint = [self convertPoint:startPos toView:sv];
if ([sv pointInside:subviewPoint withEvent:nil]) {
    ...
```

You might also want to check whether the `-[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]` message can replace the entire subview-searching loop.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Option 1 worked. Don't have time to try option 2 right now but will do so later.

Comment: OK, option 2 took less time to try out than I thought, and it works fine too.